# Route [crops.restore] not defined

Tags: php, laravel-8

I created a resource controller. The problem is when I code a route in my view, the browser displays **Route [crops.restore] not defined.** I run the php artisan route:list command and I realize that the route does not exist in the route list.

My controller is this

```
// Display all crops
public function index(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->has('trashed')) {
        $records = Crop::onlyTrashed()
            ->get();
    } else {
        $records = Crop::get();
    }

    return view('crops.index', compact('records'));
}

//restore a file
public function restore(Request $request, $id)
{
    Crop::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

My route

```
// Crop controllers
Route::resource('crops', 'CropsController');
```

My View

```
@foreach ($records as $crops)



//code ...



@if(request()->has('trashed'))
   <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-left mr-1" href="/crops/{{ $crops['id'] }}/edit">Edit</a>
   <a href="{{ route('crops.restore', $crops->id) }}" class="btn btn-success">Restore</a>
@else
 <form method="POST" class="float-left" action="{{ route('crops.destroy', $crops->id) }}">
     @csrf
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete btn-sm " title='Delete'>Delete</button>
 </form>
@endif

@endforeach
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Because `restore` is not part of [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller), and you cannot create a route with just adding a function. If you need `crops.restore`, add the route in `web.php` and refer to the function in the Resource Controller you created

Comment: Another docs that you could read. [Supplementing Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers)

Comment: What URL are you calling when you get this error? And do you have `crops.restore` somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore provide this methods in your controller: index, store, edit, update, show, destroy. If you want redirect to your custom method like restore your have to rewrite your route in this matter:

`Route::get('/restore', [App\Http\Controllers\CropsController::class, 'restore']);`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the route in the `web.php` file. For example:

```
Route::get('/restore', '\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@restore');
```

Comment: Thanks, sir problem solved.